# How to increase timeout for queries in Hector?

Tags: cassandra, hector

Im using `HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery`
and set rows count to 1 million (with setRowCount() method), but get a `TimedOutException()`.

Is there a way to set the timeout from client?

I have tried various setters in `CassandraHostConfigurator` but it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the `rpc_timeout` setting in `cassandra.yaml` meaning you config the setting server-side per each node. Checkout [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hector-users/pjSbdBnVifM) for some more details.

Comment: so there is no relevant setter in `CassandraHostConfigurator`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing the timeout, you should page through your data in smaller batches.

CQL clients like the [native Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) do this automatically: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0